# Creating a smooth 3D solid from 3D point cloud

Tags: graphics3d, data, image3d

I have set of 3D data points in the form of a .csv file. I import this file into Mathematica as such:

```
data = Import["C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\project\\data.csv"];
```

[image]

and when I use ListPointPlot3D to visualize them, I get the following image

```
ListPointPlot3D[data]
```

[image]

But I need to form the 3D solid region that is formed by these points. I neeed a smooth 3D solid.

How can I go about creating that image?

Note: For those who are interested, here is the data:
[github link](https://github.com/gunsuer/mathematica_data)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
data = Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gunsuer/mathematica_data/main/dat9.csv"];
NonConvexHullMesh = ResourceFunction["NonConvexHullMesh"];
mesh = NonConvexHullMesh[data, .05];
Show[mesh, ListPointPlot3D[data]]
```

[image: mesh]

Your data is very flat. You might want to try PCA and rescaling to get it a more solid looking mesh you can manipulate afterwards:

```
pcad = Standardize@PrincipalComponents[data];
mesh = NonConvexHullMesh[pcad, .7];
Show[mesh, ListPointPlot3D[pcad]]
```

[image: pca mesh]

Comment: Looks perfect, but I came across an error while introducing NonConvexHullMesh. It says "Privilege violation for file or directory"

Comment: @jah you probably don't have permission to download resource functions to the usual directory. Look up this error on this site.

Comment: OK I got it working, but how can I make this transparent. Because I also have to plot data with shapes similar to the one above, inside one another?

Comment: @jah do something like `Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], GrayLevel[.7], Opacity[.05], mesh, Opacity[1], ... <other primitives> ...}]` - that said transparency doesn't work that well - I'd recommend exporting the model and working in Blender.

Comment: I see. How can I export this to blender?

Comment: @jah using `Export["model.obj",mesh]` as a Wavefront OBJ or some other appropriate 3D format - [see here](https://wolfram.com/xid/0jh4osxt-2h3ht8)